# Get Match Data On top

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have multiple like operator on different columns as below:

```
SELECT d.ID ,d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode,d.LegalName,d.ShipperCode,d.PrimaryUserId,d.PrimaryContactId,              
       FROM Dealer AS d              
       LEFT JOIN Country c on c.Id=d.CountryId              
       LEFT JOIN [User] u on u.Id=d.PrimaryUserId              
       LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs on rs.Id=d.RegistrationSourceId              
       WHERE d.TenantId='4c0a42de-6ce5-4faa-8b5d-da4d7c3294b4' AND 
       (
        u.UserName LIKE '%AQ%' 
        OR d.DealerCode LIKE '%AQ%' 
        OR d.LegalName LIKE '%AQ%' 
        OR d.ShipperCode LIKE '%AQ%'
       ) 
       ORDER BY d.DealerCode ASC
```

Is it possible to find that row set first(on top) which have exact match value with any one of these column value

Comment: Replace `LIKE '%AQ%'` on `= 'AQ'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try a UNION - that should allow you to list two sets of data one after the other (untested):

```
SELECT d.ID 
       ,d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode,d.LegalName, ...
   FROM Dealer AS d              
   LEFT JOIN Country c on c.Id=d.CountryId              
   LEFT JOIN [User] u on u.Id=d.PrimaryUserId              
   LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs on rs.Id=d.RegistrationSourceId              
   WHERE d.TenantId='4c0a42de-6ce5-4faa-8b5d-da4d7c3294b4' AND 
   (
    u.UserName = 'AQ' 
    OR d.DealerCode = 'AQ' 
    OR d.LegalName = 'AQ' 
    OR d.ShipperCode = 'AQ'
   ) 
UNION
   SELECT d.ID , d.DealerCode,d.AffiliationCode, ...
   FROM Dealer AS d              
   LEFT JOIN Country c on c.Id=d.CountryId              
   LEFT JOIN [User] u on u.Id=d.PrimaryUserId              
   LEFT JOIN RegistrationSource rs on rs.Id=d.RegistrationSourceId              
   WHERE d.TenantId='4c0a42de-6ce5-4faa-8b5d-da4d7c3294b4' AND 
   (
    u.UserName LIKE '%AQ%' 
    OR d.DealerCode LIKE '%AQ%' 
    OR d.LegalName LIKE '%AQ%' 
    OR d.ShipperCode LIKE '%AQ%'
   ) 
   ORDER BY d.DealerCode ASC
```

If there is more than a "first one" you might have to restrict using `TOP 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` to make rows with exact match appears on top, for example :

```
......
......
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN 
        u.UserName = 'AQ' 
        OR d.DealerCode = 'AQ' 
        OR d.LegalName = 'AQ' 
        OR d.ShipperCode = 'AQ'
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END), d.DealerCode
```

Related question : [MySQL order by "best match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match)

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @OrderByFeild VarChar(25)
DECLARE @OrderByOrder VarChar(5)

SELECT @OrderByFeild = SUBSTRING(@OrderBy, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @OrderBy) - 1),
       @OrderByOrder = SUBSTRING(@OrderBy, CHARINDEX(' ', @OrderBy) + 1, LEN(@OrderBy))

IF @OrderByFeild = 'DealerCode' and @OrderByOrder = 'ASC'
    BEGIN

```
--Your Select Statement Here..
    ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN d.DealerCode LIKE ''+@SearchQuery+''  THEN 5 
     WHEN d.DealerCode LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 4 
     WHEN u.UserName LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 3 
     WHEN d.LegalName LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 2
     WHEN d.ShipperCode LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 1   END
END
```

ELSE IF @OrderByFeild = 'DealerCode'
    BEGIN

```
--Your Select Statement Here..
    ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN d.DealerCode LIKE ''+@SearchQuery+''  THEN 1 
     WHEN d.DealerCode LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 2 
     WHEN u.UserName LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 3 
     WHEN d.LegalName LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 4
     WHEN d.ShipperCode LIKE '%'+@SearchQuery+'%' THEN 5   END

END
```

ELSE
    BEGIN

```
    --Your Select Statement Here..
    -- ANY Other sorting you need to do
END
```