# Advanced ORDER BY when searching

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

We have made a search field where you can search for multiple ingredients and find recipes.

We would like to sort the recipes according to the recipe with most ingredients from the search box.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchquery = $_POST['search'];

$vals = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $searchquery) . "'";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM opskrifter WHERE id IN 
(SELECT opskrifterid FROM ingredienser WHERE ing_name IN ('$vals'))") or die("search failed");
```

Is it possible to sort them?

EDIT:
Recipe-table

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|   id    | name     |  procedure  |  category  |  image_url |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|       1 | Sausage  | Fry it      | Main dish  | www....com |  |
|       2 | Pizza    | Bake it     | Main dish  | www....com |  |
|       3 | Burger   | Eat it      | Main dish  | www....com |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

Ingredient-table

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|   id    | recipeid |  ing_num    |  ing_meas  |   ing_name |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|       1 | 1        | 1           | stack      | sausage    |  |
|       2 | 2        | 200         | g          | wheat      |  |
|       3 | 2        | 100         | g          | beef       |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

***UPDATE***

I've tried implementing the solution from Beginner/Raymond:

```
"SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `total_ingredients`
  FROM opskrifter as k
     , ingredienser as i
 WHERE k.id = i.opskrifterid 
   AND i.ing_name IN ($vals)
   GROUP BY k.id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"
```

Where `$vals = "'" . str_replace(",", "', '", $searchquery) . "'";`
and `$searchsquery = $_POST['search']; //From the searchfield`

Unfortunately the search only takes the first word into account, example:
"salt, pasta" it shows every recipe containing salt. But the recipe containing both ingredients is not the top sorted one.

What did I miss?

Comment: please provide your table structure, sample data and the desired output for more clearer explanation for the viewers

Comment: What you're searching for is 'relevance' where you order by the most matched terms. Something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match

Comment: @Beginner Here's the tables :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer below before me just missed a `GROUP BY` that's why it only returns one row

```
SELECT k.id
     , k.name
     , COUNT(*) as `total_ingredients`
  FROM receipts as k
     , ingredients as i
 WHERE k.id = i.receipt_id 
   AND i.ing_name IN ('sausage','beef', 'wheat', 'sauce', 'flour', 'wheat', 'beef', 'ketsup', 'onion', 'garlic')
   GROUP BY k.id, k.name
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

[**JS Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6ad0/4)

Comment: @Raymond I've tried implementing your solution, take a look above :)

Answer (score 0):

Jacob!

I think this query can solve your problem.
Please, try it.

```
SELECT k.id
     , k.name
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM opskrifter k
     , ingredienser i
 WHERE k.id = i.opskrifterid 
   AND i.ing_name IN ('sausage','beef', 'wheat')
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: unfortunately, it only shows one recipe, when ordering by count :(