# Mysql Query List order in LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table Structure is

```
id | name 
--------
1    Test name

2    Test name1

3    Name1

4    name2 

5    Name6

6    Name7

7    AA Name1

8   AA Name2
```

if am using query

```
select name from table like '%na%' order by name asc limit 5;
```

Result will be

```
AA Name1

AA Name2

Name1

Name2

Name6
```

I need a query to show following result

```
Name1

Name2

Name6

Name7

AA Name1
```

Because i've table 
 If i typed p i need result 
perl, php, phython before 'apple script'

[image]

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I've a table contains same name repeating rows like bob smith, bob morgan, bob rals, alias bob, steward bob, rals steward etc. if i type bob i need bob starting name will come first after alias bob will show example 
[link](https://erail.in/) type madu in from

Comment: That is not a logic

Comment: This will give you the expected result (at least for your example data and without the stars of course). 
select name from table like '%na%' order by id asc limit 5;
But I don't understand your intention behind this.

Comment: you may refer use locate function in order by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` to determine if the record starts with `na`.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%na%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE 'na%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
LIMIT 5;
```

Or you could order by the location of `na` in the record by using `INSTR`.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%na%'
ORDER BY INSTR(name,'na'), name
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: The case should be the opposite, since 0 sorts before 1.