# MySQL: how to order a result if certain records contain specific words

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to show a query result displaying titles which contain **Summer festival** and **Summer festivals** ordered first in the list of records.

This very basic SQL query gives following result:

```
SELECT title FROM items


title
-----------------
Just a test
Just another test
New test
Testing
Summer festival
Summer festivals
```

My goal is to display the result as following:

```
title
-----------------
Summer festival
Summer festivals
Just a test
Just another test
New test
Testing
```

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try conditional order by

```
SELECT title 
FROM items
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE '%Summer festival%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, title
```

Answer (score 0):

To order by a specific string you could use something like this

```
SELECT title FROM items ORDER BY (CASE WHEN title = 'Summer festival' THEN 1 WHEN title = 'Summer Festivals' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
```

That should give you your output you require by ordering by two specific strings first then displaying the rest of the results after.