# Full Text Search on MySQL, but word order must matter

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, myisam, match-against

I'm doing a MySQL search using MATCH/AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE, but I need that the word's order matters.

Assuming that I have the following content on the column "names" on table "users":

```
  +---------------------------------+
  | names                           |
  +---------------------------------+
  | RONSON SIMPSON HOMER JAY        |
  | SIMPSON RONSON HOMER JAY        | 
  | RONSON SIMPSON JAY HOMER        |
  | SIMPSON RONSON JAY HOMER        |
  +---------------------------------+
```

If I'm looking for SIMPSON HOMER, then I need that the very first result be:

- SIMPSON RONSON HOMER JAY

FYI, now I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(names) AGAINST('+SIMPSON +HOMER') AS relevance FROM users WHERE MATCH(names) AGAINST('+SIMPSON +HOMER' IN BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING relevance > 0.2 ORDER BY  relevance DESC, names ASC LIMIT 30;
```

*I'm asking because I didn't find a good answer on SOF or the rest of the internet - the most closest topic was this: [MySQL order by "best match"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match)*, but answers aren't working to me.

*I also apologize for the bad example.*

*Please, no %LIKE% suggestions, because performance of the query is important in my environment*

Answer (score 0):

```
... AGAINST('+"SIMPSON HOMER"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (`"`) characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Note also that using a fulltext `MATCH ... AGAINST` **and** `LIKE` in the same query results in the optimizer using the fulltext index first, then filtering only the matched rows using `LIKE`, so it can be quite valid and perform well... though it should not be needed, here.

Comment: Excuse me, sir. How can I mix MATCH/AGAINST and LIKE? (in the context of my question). I've been trying without luck. Thank You!

Comment: @eplazai - `WHERE (..LIKE..) AND (MATCH...)` will do the `MATCH` first, then further filter with the `LIKE` (or `RLIKE`).