# Hibernate search - exact matches first

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do a fulltext search, the only problem i am facing is the fact, that  excact matches are not on top of the list. If i search for "cat" then i get "blablacatcc", "asdcatsada" and then "cat".  Is there a way to have it sorted like that? With exact matches on top?

my code:

```
final String[] fields = Stream.of(
            Product_.casNumber.getName(),
            Product_.casIndexName.getName(),
            Product_.chemicalName.getName(),
            path(Product_.alternativeNames, ProductName_.alternativeName)
    ).toArray(String[]::new);
    final QueryBuilder builder = manager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();
    final Sort sort = builder.sort().byScore().createSort();
    final Query query = builder.keyword().wildcard().onFields(fields).matching("*" + pattern.toLowerCase() + "*").createQuery();
    return manager.createFullTextQuery(query, Product.class).setSort(sort).getResultList();
```

Comment: How does it sort the results without your custom sorter?

Comment: It seems random, prolly it does not sort at all

Comment: Could you please provide imports?

Comment: `import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Sort;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;`

Comment: Thanks, which dependencies do you use? I can't see `sort()`  method on QueryBuilder class using org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:4.3.0

Comment: org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.10.0.Final

Comment: I found out only one solution for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725941/mysql-order-by-best-match

Here in answers is an idea to create order by-case. 
My best proposal to sort the collection in this way after you got the result. 
Of course if you don't need limits for it.

Comment: Going with raw sql is not a possibility

Comment: Sure, that’s why I talk about sorting the result collection with Java. Not using sql