# Why MATCH AGAINST not return relevance results

Tags: mysql

I have simple table but cant get relevance results for some reason.

In my table i have next records

```
Кухненски шкафове и модули
Офис модули
Модули за спалня
Модулни секции
Модулни кухни
Модулни гардероби
```

When i execute this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  name,
  MATCH(name) AGAINST('моду*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM category scs   
WHERE 
  MATCH(name) AGAINST('моду*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I expect 1st to return all strings that start with 'моду' like this

```
Модули за спалня
Модулни секции
Модулни кухни
Модулни гардероби
Офис модули
Кухненски шкафове и модули
```

but im getting order like this

```
Кухненски шкафове и модули
Модули за спалня
Офис модули
Модулни секции 
Модулни кухни 
Модулни гардероби
```

How can i order them 1st to return all string that start with searched phrase ?

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5f1fc/2)

Comment: The fulltext search does not/cannot rank by word position. You can sort the results (that you find using the fulltext search) afterwards by using e.g. something from [MySQL order by "best match"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18725941).

Comment: @Solarflare there are using LIKE method can same things be done with MATCH AGAINST or I have to switch my query to use LIKE method?

Comment: You search using your current fulltext search. You just use the order by part from that answer.

Comment: @Solarflare this will do the job. thx your star